# How to limit number of reads from Amazon S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, web-hosting

I'm hosting a static website in Amazon S3 with CloudFront. Is there a way to set a limit for how many reads (for example per month) will be allowed for my Amazon S3 bucket in order to make sure I don't go above my allocated budget?

Answer (score 2):

If you are concerned about going over a budget, I would recommend [Creating a Billing Alarm to Monitor Your Estimated AWS Charges](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/monitor_estimated_charges_with_cloudwatch.html).

AWS is designed for large-scale organizations that **care more about providing a reliable service to customers** than staying within a particular budget. For example, if their allocated budget was fully consumed, they would not want to stop providing services to their customers. They might, however, want to tweak their infrastructure to reduce costs in future, such as changing the [Price Class for a CloudFront Distribution](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/PriceClass.html) or using AWS WAF to prevent bots from consuming too much traffic.

Your static website will be rather low-cost. The biggest factor will likely be **Data Transfer** rather than charges for Requests. Changing the Price Class should assist with this. However, the only true way to stop accumulating Data Transfer charges is to stop serving content.

Answer (score 0):

You could activate CloudTrail data read events for the bucket, create a CloudWatch Event Rule to trigger an AWS Lambda Function that increments the number of reads per object in an Amazon DynamoDB table and restrict access to the objects once a certain number of reads has been reached.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this. What you are suggesting definitely makes sense, but I was hoping that there's a less complicated way to do this that possibly also is a bit more intelligent in terms of allocating the reads more fairly. For example, if a lot of calls are coming from a bot-like service, it would be great if the reads could be allocated more fairly towards users compared to a more first come first served basis.

Comment: You can put an AWS WAF with a rate-based rule in front of the CloudFront distribution to block traffic from clients that exceed a certain amount of requests in a given amount of time. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/ddos-get-started-rate-based-rules.html

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for is a very typical question in AWS. Unfortunately with near infinite scale, comes near infinite spend.

While you can put a WAF, that is actually meant for security rather than scale restrictions. From a cost-perspective, I'd be more worried about the bandwidth charges than I would be able S3 requests cost.

Plus once you put things like Cloudfront or Lambda, it gets hard to limit all this down.

The best way to limit, is to put Billing Alerts on your account -- and you can tier them, so you get a $10, $20, $100 alerts, up until the point you're uncomfortable with. And then either manually disable the website -- or setup a lambda function to disable it for you.